# ms access combobox does not autofill

Tags: combobox, ms-access-2010

MS Access 2010

I have a form that provides a text value to a combobox on another form but the combobox autofill does not respond to the text data that is provided by the OnClick event.  I receive an error 2237 the data is not in the list.  I need this to work as some of the comboboxes have thousands of records and schrolling this list is therefore not practical. Here is the code that inserts the text in the combobox:

```
Private Sub tOK_Click()
Dim p As String
Dim f As String
Dim c As String
Dim txtResult As String
Dim pFrmName As String
Dim frmName As String
Dim ctrl As String

On Error GoTo errHandler
pFrmName = Me.pFrmName
frmName = Me.frmName
ctrl = Me.ctrlName
p = pFrmName
f = frmName
c = ctrl

If p = c Then
    Forms(f).SetFocus
    Forms(f)(c).Text = Me.txtResult
Else
     Forms(f)(p)(c).SetFocus
     Forms(f)(p)(c).Text = Me.txtResult

End If
```

Comment: check the properties on the data tab of the combobox that is producing your error and ensure that limit to list = NO and allow value list edits = Yes. You might also want to run a check before hand to ensure that the text being entered is in the table the combobox is bound to.

Comment: Also, why are you passing variable to variable? why not just assign the variables p, f, and c the original object names?

Comment: Thanks Chris, the bound column must be the ID field.  I changed the combobox query so the first column equals Me.textResult and the ID field is the second column.  The Me.textResult value appears in the combobox but the autofill does not fire, the bound column is wrong (as mentioned).  If I enter the full text name of the combobox field there is no error so Access recognizes that the text is in the list but if Me.textResult is only the first few letters of the field name I get error 2237 when I leave the combobox.  

The passing of variables is an error that I will fix.

Comment: ahhhh ok i see now. Yes, autofill of a combo box will not work unless text is being type by a user into the combo box. One possible solution you could try is an auto fill on the me.TextResult. Query the data from the table using the LIKE '*' & 'Your Text Here' & '*' in your queries where clause.

Comment: My combobox is accessed by keyboard normally, I want the user to be able to access it on the web through a remote access app (my software is based on QuickBooks desktop so it's not web based).  Nevertheless I will try it, it's an interesting idea.  I notice that if I use the keyboard from Windows Mobility Center it works with each keystroke.  Thanks.

Comment: I may have found an answer using Sendkeys which activates the Autofill - it still needs cleanup but it works.

    Private Sub Combo0_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As 
    Single, Y As Single)
    Dim kys As String
    DoCmd.Save
    vkbdData 'returns text for combobox Combo0
    kys = Combo0.Text
    SendKeys (kys)

    DoCmd.Save

    End Sub

Comment: I can select an item from a combobox but only the first item that matched the pattern.  For example if I enter "032" the first item that starts with "032" is selected i.e "032.01"  but I if select "032.02" from the drop-down the combobox reverts to "032.01".  If I enter "032.02" my Access keyboard app the combobox displays "032.02".  The problem is the user will have to know each of thousands of codes to select a code.

Thanks Chris for your comment regarding key stroke input which led me to Sendkeys.  I tried Sendkeys previously but for reasons I don't recall I failed.

Comment: Here's the function, when the combobox is not the first control selected the selection say "032.01" does not select a value from the combobox.  I am using the MouseUp event.

Comment: If IsNull(Screen.ActiveForm.Controls.Parent) Then
    frmName = Screen.ActiveForm.ActiveControl.Name
    Else
    frmName = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
End If
pFrmName = Screen.ActiveForm.ActiveControl.Name

ctrlcaption = ""

ctrlName = Screen.ActiveControl.Name
       sValue = Screen.ActiveControl.Text
    
  vkbdData = keyBoardPopUp(frmName, pFrmName, ctrlName, ctrlcaption, sValue)

End If

sParameters = pFrmName & ">" & frmName & "|" & ctrlName & "^" & ctrlcaption & "~" & sValue
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_keyboard", , , , , , sParameters

Comment: I apologize for the last comment.  The issue is not resolved but I think I will eventually solve it so consider this question closed.  Thank you Chris.